# opengl es how to set boolean in shader

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-3.0

I want to set boolean value in my fragment shader beacuse i need to recognize when to color objects by multiplying. but i dont know how to acess this boolean variable textured from java code. Project is created in java for android, using opengl es 3.0.

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 vColor;
uniform bool textured;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;

void main(){
    if(textured){
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoordinate);
        gl_FragColor *= vColor;
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use an `int` rather than a `bool`: `if (textured != 0)`

Alternatively you can pass a floating point value which weights the texture:

```c
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 vColor;
uniform float textured;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = 
       vColor * mix(vec4(1.0), texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoordinate), textured);
}
```

[`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) linearly interpolate between two values. Look at the expression:

```py
gl_FragColor = 
    vColor * mix(vec4(1.0), texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoordinate), textured);
```

If `textured == 0.0`, the color is multiplied by `vec4(1.0)`:

```py
gl_FragColor = vColor * vec4(1.0);
```

If `textured == 1.0`, then the color is multiplied by the color returned from the texture lookup:

```py
gl_FragColor = vColor * texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoordinate);
```

If `0.0 < textured < 1.0`, then `vec4(1.0)` and the texture color are interpolated linearly.

---

Furthermore be careful when you look up a texture in a condition statement. See [OpenGL ES 1.1 Full Specification - 6 Texture Accesses; page 110](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf#page=116):

> Accessing mip-mapped textures within the body of a non-uniform conditional block gives an undefined value. A non-uniform conditional block is a block whose execution cannot be determined at compile time.

Comment: but mix will not causes any problems when i set black texture?

Comment: @Bogus No? Why?

Comment: because when texture will be black then some colors will be set to 0.0 i think. then color will be multiplyed by 1.0 not 0.0. I want to use mixed because this looks great, but it will cause another problem. My code uses last used texture when i not determine a new one. Meybe i must deactivate texture, but i do not know how.

Comment: @Bogus I've no Ide what you try to say. You don't need to deactivate textures. If no texture is bound, then the value returned by the texture lookup is 0.0. Have you tried the code? It works fine. Read the code:  `mix(vec4(1.0), texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoordinate), textured)`. If `textured==0.0` then this expression returns `vec4(1.0)`. Anyway I've explained that in the answer, you just have to read it.